# How to set html id to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$('#submit').click(
    function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let number = 0;

        $("#tasklist").append("<li id='addedtask number'>" + $('#task_to_add').val() + "</li>" +
            "<form action='index.html' method='get'> <input type='submit' id='remove index' value='remove'></input> </form>");


    }
);//end of submit
```

I am adding this button dynamically with jquery and I would like to increment the id of this button, how would I do this?
I would like it to be equivalent of this after the first time it should be:

```
<input type='submit' id='remove index 1' value='remove>
```

and after second:

```
<input type='submit' id='remove index 2' value='remove>
```

If I try to put a variable int the id like 'remove index myvar' i think it will just treat myvar like a string. Is there a way to get to be treated like a variable?
 Please advise and thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to concatenate strings?

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to add these elements?

Comment: Use Vue JS or React for these things.

Comment: Mutating IDs is probably not the best way to do this. What are you trying to accomplish that data attributes can't do?

Comment: @SLaks I do not want it to be a string, I want it to remain as a variable so I can increment it

Comment: @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane I am adding  elements to an <li> list,and i want to have a remove button to remove each specific item- i want to correspond each remove button to the element that it is next to

Comment: You can do this easily by using ordinal selectors: $("#tasklist li").eq(1) and forget the ID assignments.

Answer (score 1):

```
var currentId = 1;
$("#submit").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $("#tasklist").append(
        "<li id='addedtask'>" +
            $('#task_to_add').val() +
        "</li>" +
        "<form action='index.html' method='get'>" +
            "<input type='submit' id='remove-index-" + currentId++ + "' value='remove'></input>" +
        "</form>"
    );
});
```